# Expected Value of a function of independent variables & non-independent variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, covariance, variance

Assume we have a sequence of i.i.d normal random variables ${Z_t}$, with mean 0 and variance 3.

1. Let $X_t = Z_tZ_{t+1}$

I understand that the expected value of $X_t$ can be written as $E[X_t]=E[Z_tZ_{t+1}]=E[Z_t]E[Z_{t+1}]$ because they are i.i.d variables. But how about $E[X_t^2]$?

$$E[X_t^2]=E[Z_t^2Z_{t+1}^2]$$

Since $Z_t$ is not independent of itself, can we write $E[Z_t^2Z_{t+1}^2]=E[Z_t^2]E[Z_{t+1}^2]$?

2. Let $X_t = Z_tcos(t)+Z_{t+1}sin(t+1)$ where $Z_t$ is not independent of variable $t$.

How can we deal with  $E[X_t^2]$ in this case?

For example, let's take one term from $E[X_t^2]$

$$E[Z_tZ_{t+1}cos(t)sin(t+1)]$$

can we further expand this term since $Z_t$ and $Z_{t+1}$ are i.i.d random variables?

Comment: Note that $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$ and $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Now use the preceding formulas you have $E((XY)^2)=Var(XY)-E(XY)^2=Var(XY)-(Cov(X,Y)-E(X)E(Y))^2$.

Comment: Yes $E(U^2V^2)=E(U^2)E(V^2)$ when $U$ and $V$ are independent since then $U^2$ and $V^2$ are independent. Yes $E(cUV)=cE(UV)$, always, and $cE(UV)=cE(U)E(V)$ when $U$ and $V$ are independent. Are these your questions?

Comment: @SaeidAli Why do you want to embark the OP to computing covariances and variances when they are only interested in expectations?

Comment: @Did Yes, this was my first question. So is that saying if X and Y are iid, then f(X) and f(Y) are also iid if there're no other variables associated in these functions?

Comment: Indeed if $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. then $(g(X),g(Y))$ is i.i.d.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your help! Do you happen to know if the expected value in my 2nd question can be further expanded or not??

Comment: Of course: $$E(X_t^2)=3\cos^2(t)+3\sin^2(t+1)$$

Comment: @Did I am sorry, but I do not understand how you get to this answer. Since $Z_t$ and t are not independent, where did $Z_t$ terms go in this case?

Comment: Here $t$ is deterministic hence $t$ is independent of everything. To check this by another method, you might want to expand $X_t^2$ and to collect the expectation of each term, using the identities given in my first comment.

Comment: @Did Got you. Is that saying if $t$ was not a deterministic variable, then we cannot get to this conclusion?

Comment: Depends of what you replace it by.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot for your help!!!